# Having Some Serious Issues With Decimal Types (Complex Circles) Cdecimal

Tags: python, anaconda

I am having some issues with decimal holdings.

1. I am currently working out some formulas which require the use of circles (non Pi) as a factor; or ratio determinant.
2. When using this type of data I am often using repeating infinite numbers. Is there a way I can convince Python to treat them as such without defining each value on its own through the decimal module?

This requires exact representation as it is calculating planetary and atomic orbitals. There are millions of possibilities, so I can't really use traps or ceilings.

```
For example, I often see rounding errors even with Cdecimal like this one:
initial_input_over_n 
5.500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
initial_input_over_np 
53.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
```

This is compounded when you start to multiply them together and divide; where the whole ratio should be 1, because it is two infinite numbers (circles) divided together, but I wind up with an off number because of the rounded choice.

It's extremely important to keep rounding from happening for this. Entropy has to be removed from the system.

This is necessary, because I need to work these numbers down to one specific number to add into the rest of the system, without using any forced numbers.

So far I have tried the decimal types but can't figure out what the right code would be to make these numbers stay the way they are intended. I am using so many different inputs that I need it to be flexible as it gets into the hundreds of millions.

```
import decimal
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 64

input("Press Enter To Continue ...\n\n\n"

"# Input = Total number of points\n"
"# N     = Number of points traveled\n"
"# NP    = Number of points remaining\n\n")

IN = decimal.Decimal (input("Enter Input: "))
N = decimal.Decimal (input("Enter N: "))
NP = decimal.Decimal (input("Enter NP: "))

IN = 0.5 if IN == 0 else IN
N = 0.5 if N == 0 else N
NP = 0.5 if NP == 0 else NP

_input = IN
n = N
np = NP

# - Used to allow lowercase letters in code. Ensures no division by zero 
errors occur.

# input = total number of points
# n     = number of points traveled
# np    = number of points remaining


                     # ----------------- #
                     #    Read Ratios    #
                     # ----------------- #

initial_sine_base       = _input + n + np

initial_sine_input      = initial_sine_base / _input
initial_sine_n          = initial_sine_base / n
initial_sine_np         = initial_sine_base / np

initial_sine_ratio      = initial_sine_input + initial_sine_n + 
initial_sine_np
initial_sine_over_base  = initial_sine_ratio / initial_sine_base

initial_input_over_base = _input / initial_sine_ratio
initial_n_over_base     = n / initial_sine_ratio
initial_np_over_base    = np / initial_sine_ratio

initial_input_over_n    = _input / initial_sine_n
initial_input_over_np   = _input / initial_sine_np
initial_input_over_nnp  = _input / (initial_sine_n + initial_sine_np)

initial_n_over_input    = n / initial_sine_input
initial_n_over_np       = n / initial_sine_np
initial_n_over_inputnp  = n / (initial_sine_input + initial_sine_np)

initial_np_over_input   = np / initial_sine_input
initial_np_over_n       = np / initial_sine_n
initial_np_over_inputnp = np / (initial_sine_input + initial_sine_n)

#Subdivides

check   = (n * _input * np)
unknown = (n * _input * np) / initial_sine_base

#Circle Ratios

plus_one  = (_input + _input + n + n + np) / n
minus_one = (_input + _input + n + np) / n

sub_divide_half = 2
```

Another example is the multiplication or division of two like circles;

```
plus_one  = (_input + _input + n + n + np) / n
minus_one = (_input + _input + n + np) / n

#Circle Ratios
plus_one 33.18181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818
minus_one 32.18181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818
```

Once I start to divide these together or use any operators they fall apart, but overall they are only 1 whole number away from another.

The goal is to keep the ratios completely stable, so I can make subdivide half equal to 2 through only the inputs. I just need to get it so that Python calculates the appropriate ratios down to the exact decimal. With the way I am doing this, everything gets messed up when I take it a little further and enter some more complex computations.

This must all be done through only division or multiplication, so shortcuts are off the table.

```
The inputs I used for reference were input = 118, n = 11, np = 107
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I often see rounding errors even with Cdecimal like this
>   one: initial_input_over_n 
>   5.500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

This can happen in 2 situations:

1. You have done an operation with a real (i.e. a decimal created by setting up a decimal from an integer or a real; `decimal.Decimal(2.5)`). The real will be imprecise and may be setting your decimal to something you do not expect. Prime example: `decimal.Decimal(1/3)` will be off.
2. More likely: You have not set the rounding to the way you expect it; the decimal module supports 8 ways of rounding. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes) for the available values.

As an aside: The following code will lead to problems:

```
IN = 0.5 if IN == 0 else IN
```

You set IN to a float if it is input as zero. Will make divisions fail.

```
>>> b = d.Decimal('123')
>>> IN = 0.5
>>> b / IN
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean about making divisions fail? They don't fail at all when you actually run the program without decimal imported. It's what keeps things working properly. That is required as part of it. There's no getting around it, as it is how natural objects operate.

I'll keep trying, but do you have any suggestions on how to write this so that the roundings can be done? Specifically so things like 5.000000001 get rounded down to 5 instead of up, and so that inifinite numbers stay infinite? That is what I have been trying but it always gives errors. That's why I am asking.

Comment: What is unclear about the transcript I supplied? If you divide a decimal by a float (and your code does that in some situations), it will fail. *do you have any suggestions on how to write this so that the roundings can be done? * No, I do not know your requirements. The 8 different rounding methods I mentioned in the answer all do something different. How could I know what you want? When should 5.000000001 be rounded to 5, and when should it not be rounded?

Comment: It's ok for now. Figured a fix for it to use in the meantime. In case you are wondering what I was meaning, this is the full code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q3x6cdqbk3sh5i/First%20Iteration%3B%20NP%20Calculator.py?dl=0

No more questions, just thought you might want to understand what